# Efficient way to load file into 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to take a list of transactional data and sum it to a 2d numpy array.  My data looks like the following:

```
person, product, date, val
A, x, 1/1/2013, 10
A, x, 1/10/2013, 10
B, x, 1/2/2013, 20
B, y, 1/4/2013, 15
A, y, 1/8/2013, 20
C, z, 2/12/2013, 40
```

I need to get the output into a 2d array, with each person as a row, and the product as columns.  The date will be dropped, and the values are summed.

The output will look like this:

```
[[20, 20, 0],[20, 15, 0],[0, 0, 40]]
```

Here's what I have that functions, but it is really slow (I've got 110,000,000 records):

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
import pandas as pd
from scipy import sparse
import os
import assoc


#read in data to a dict object - sums scripts by tuple (doc, drug)
dictObj = {}
rawData = 'subset.txt'
with open(rawData) as infile:
for line in infile:
    parts = line.split(',')
    key = (parts[0],parts[1])
    val = float(parts[3])
    if key in dictObj:
        dictObj[key] += val
    else:
        dictObj[key] = val
infile.close()

print "stage 1 done"
#get the number of doctors and the number of drugs
keys =  dictObj.keys()
docs = list(set([x[0] for x in keys]))
drugs = sorted(list(set([x[1] for x in keys])))

#read through the dict and build out a 2d numpy array 
docC = 0
mat = np.empty([len(docs),len(drugs)])
for doc in docs:
drugC = 0
for drug in drugs:
    key = (doc,drug)
    if key in dictObj:
        mat[(docC,drugC)] = dictObj[(key)]
            else:
        mat[(docC,drugC)] = 0
    drugC += 1
docC+=1
```

I had posted a similar thread earlier (here - [Transformation of transactions to numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179393/transformation-of-transactions-to-numpy-array)), and everyone responded that Pandas was the way to go, but I can't for the life of me get the Pandas output into the right format.  I can't pass a Pandas dataFrame to the kmeans or apriori algorithms I have, and no matter how I arrange the dataFrame, the df.values gets me to a multiIndex series (which simplifies down to 1 long array!).  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might do something like

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("trans.csv", skipinitialspace=True)
>>> w = df.groupby(["person", "product"])["val"].sum().reset_index()
>>> w
  person product  val
0      A       x   20
1      A       y   20
2      B       x   20
3      B       y   15
4      C       z   40
>>> w.pivot("person", "product").fillna(0)
         val        
product    x   y   z
person              
A         20  20   0
B         20  15   0
C          0   0  40
>>> w.pivot("person", "product").fillna(0).values
array([[ 20.,  20.,   0.],
       [ 20.,  15.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,  40.]])
```

which IIUC is the 2-D array you're after.  Note that you don't have to read the entire file into memory at once, you can use the `chunksize` parameter (see [the docs here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#io-chunking)) and accumulate your table piece by piece.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed.  I couldn't for the life of me get that pivot to work before.

Answer (score 1):

`recfromcsv` (or recfromtxt) will load your data into a record array

```
data=np.recfromcsv('stack20179393.txt')

rec.array([('A', ' x', ' 1/1/2013', 10), ('A', ' x', ' 1/10/2013', 10),
       ('B', ' x', ' 1/2/2013', 20), ('B', ' y', ' 1/4/2013', 15),
       ('A', ' y', ' 1/8/2013', 20), ('C', ' z', ' 2/12/2013', 40)], 
      dtype=[('person', 'S1'), ('product', 'S2'), ('date', 'S10'), ('val', '<i4')])

data.person
# chararray((['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C'], dtype='|S1')

data.val
# array([10, 10, 20, 15, 20, 40])
```

Since `person` can occur in any order, and with different frequency (3A, 2B, 1C), you can't readily turn this into a 2D array.  So you may still need to iterate through the records, collecting values in something like a dictionary - I'd recommend a `collections.defaultdict`.  `itertools.groupby` is also a handy tool for collecting values into groups.  However, it would require sorting your records.

with a defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(list)
for row in data:
    dd[row[0]].append(row[-1])
print dd
# defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': [10, 10, 20], 'C': [40], 'B': [20, 15]})
d = {}
for k,v in dd.items(): d[k] = sum(v)
print d
# {'A': 40, 'B': 35, 'C': 40}
```

or

```
dd = defaultdict(float)
for row in data:
    dd[row[0]].append(row[-1])
print dd
defaultdict(<type 'float'>, {'A': 40.0, 'C': 40.0, 'B': 35.0})
```

A sparse approach takes advantage of how `csr_matrix` sums repeated indexes

```
from scipy import sparse  
row=np.array([ord(a) for a in data.person])-65
col=np.zeros(row.shape)
sparse.csr_matrix((data.val,(row,col))).T.A
# array([[40, 35, 40]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the end of your problem, it seems that you just need to get a pandas `DataFrame` to a numpy `array`. Here is how you do that:

```
#df is your DataFrame
data = np.asarray(df)
```

So now you shouldn't have a problem with using pandas!

Comment: thanks for the response - this doesn't quite get me there though.  In order to sum on the DataFrame, I've had to call the groupby function, which returns a series, not a dataframe.  I tried both of the following: `grouped = df2.groupby(['person','product']).sum()` and `df.groupby(['person']).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.groupby('product').sum()['amount']))`.  If I use the asarray function you suggested on that output it's still 1 dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code and the size of you data then I should think it would be very slow  110,000,000 records, presumably consisting of a string, (doctor), a long string, (drug), date (dropped) and a value which is a float value.  Lets say 20 chars for doctor, (possibly not enough), and 30 for drug, (probably not enough), 4 bytes for value that is 5.5 Gi before any overheads, **then** you are duplicating it into a 2D matrix.

Unless you are running on a mainframe or a cluster I would strongly suggest restructuring to either sum as you read or stage 1 being read into a database.

You could also take a look at the possibility of using [pytables](http://www.pytables.org/moin) if Pandas is not working for you.